# DotNetNuke integrated security to SQL Server

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am installing DotNetNuke 7.0.4 to Windows 2008 R2 + IIS 7.5 + SQL 2012 machines. Trying to use Integrated Security on the initial database setup page but always get SQL login failed message. SQL server log shows DNN use [domainname\machinesname$] to connect to SQL server. I created this account on SQL but still get this error message. (can't find a login matching).

How can I resolve this issue? 
If I want to use AD authentication for my site, do I have to use this integrate security?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the application pool idenetity of your web application/website's application pool to the domain username you wish to use. Find below a link on where to navigate to.

[Specify an Identity for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your quick response! I changed the app pool account to  local network service and it works like a charm!